# GitLab CI use untracked files in repository

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm evaluating GitLab CI/CD at the moment and trying to get the pipelines working, however am having a simple(?) problem.

I'm trying to automate the build process by automatically updating ISO images. However these ISO images are not tracked by the repository and ignored in a .gitignore file. But this leads to the issue of when I try run `make` that it can't find the ISO image...

I'm just using a simple `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - make
```

And when I try running this in the GitLab CI interface, it clones the repository (without the ISO images), and then fails, as there is no rule to that make target (as the ISO images are missing). I have tried moving the files into the "build" directory which GitLab creates, however that gives the error of saying it has `failed to remove ...`

How do I use the local repository rather than having GitLab clone the repository to a "build" location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Gitlab CI with the files that are on your computer, at least you shouldn't. You could do it with an [ssh-executor](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/executors/ssh.md) that will login to a machine that stores the iso files (and it should be a server rather than your development machine) or you could have the docker executor pull them from ftp/object store. For testing purposes you can [run the builds locally](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/commands/README.md#gitlab-runner-exec) on your machine.

Comment: I see, thanks. So would you say copying the files across in a `before_script` to the build location be okay as well? (I'm using a shell runner at the moment).

Comment: @Rekovni Yes, it would be okay if the performance of that is okay with you.